# Catch - rethrow in Tibco

Tags: tibco, tibco-business-works

I have a `Catch` activity in Tibco designer. From this one I have a transition to a `CallProcess` and from the `CallProcess` two other transitions: `Success with condition` to a `Rethrow` activity and `Success with no matching condition` to some other activity (let's say `ActivityA` - could be even `Null`). When I tried to make a transition between `ActivityA` and `End` I get the error

> These activities cannot be connected: A Rethrow activity must be preceeded at some point by a Catch activity.

Why does this happen? `ActivityA` and `Rethrow` should be on different execution paths.

Practically what I want to achieve is to have a catch that based on some condition is rethrowing the exception or ends successfully.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I removed the transition to `Rethrow` activity, made the transition between `ActivityA` and `End` and then added the transition to `Rethrow` again.

I know it doesn't make sense, but this way worked.